# Chrome looks blurry and ugly on HIDPI laptop

Tags: google-chrome, display, kde, display-resolution, hdpi

I have a laptop with a 1920 x 1080 display and my problem is that Google Chrome and even Chromium looks blurry and not as clear as in Windows and it drives me nuts. It is a HIDPI display so I added `--force-device-scale-factor=1.2` to `chrome-flags.conf` to solve the problem of the UI being so small that I could barely use the browsers, I don't know if that setting has to do anything with my problem but I think I should mention it. I use Kubuntu 17.10.1.

EDIT: Here are two screenshots of my desktop.

The first is the unscaled default look of the chromium browser.
[image: Here]

The second is the scaled version, it is very blurry compared to windows, which has a sharp looking font.
[image: Here]

Comment: Yes, the 120% scaling is why images and such look blurry on web sites, for you. They are raster images and being scaled. What physical size is the screen? 12.6"? 15.6"? 5.5"?

Comment: The laptop's size is 15.6". The browser itself looks blurry and even the fonts, not only the images. If I set the scaling back to normal everything looks small.

Comment: OK. That is not really a HiDPI screen though. Could you perhaps [edit] your question and include a screenshot?

Comment: I added the screenshots to my question.

Comment: 1920x1080 is not HiDPI, it's a good quality screen, but the 1x version looks just fine. There is no need to scale it.

Comment: With the default scaling, there are lots of unused space on websites and it annoys me and also everything looks so small. Window's default scaling is 125% and I want to use that on Linux too.

Comment: Well, websites do not have to always utilize 100% of screen estate. Good design and typography rules impose a maximum line width.